# Save user's login method in cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I have an .Net MVC3 website with multiple authentication options:

- Facebook
- Google
- Websites own

When the user initially browses to the site he is asked for his/her choice of authentication and once they have either registered or logged in through a third party they are authenticated on my site.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to save the user's authentication choice in a cookie, so when they revisit the site they are logged in using their previous authentication choice (Google and Facebook automatically if they are already logged in)?
- If possible whats the best practice for creating a secure cookie in MVC3?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help

[THIS](http://www.creatingsoftware.net/2007/11/aspnet-20-forms-authentication-keeping.html)
 or
[THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx)

It can also be implemented in server side too.

Comment: Link only answers are not permitted. Please post it as a comment or repeat the important parts from the links in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SAM:

http://brockallen.com/2013/01/26/replacing-forms-authentication-with-wifs-session-authentication-module-sam-to-enable-claims-aware-identity/

This would allow you to issue a secure cookie that contains all the claims from the identity provider.